# How to access Mobile Data from Web Application?

Tags: android, ibm-cloud

I've a mobile application, which is storing data in mobile data. I want to integrate a web application to access mobile data. Can anyone provide me sample code access(CRUD Operation) mobile data?

Comment: *Can anyone provide me sample code ...?* - google search can ...

Comment: Can you access mobile DB from web app ? i don't think so. You can store your data on web through Rest Api or store it on both mobile and web.

Comment: @Sathiya1992, I am assuming that you have a Liberty Profile web application running on Bluemix and want integrate with MobileData service on Bluemix at https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobiledata/index.html#gettingstarted.  Please let me know if my assumption is correct and I can provide appropriate directions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for REST APIs in order to interact with Mobile Data you can find a list of operations as well test them out here:

[Mobile Cloud Services REST API Documentation](https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/mbaas-api/?cm_mc_uid=60766666672614388751056&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1438883341#!/data/)

If you are looking for something else please let me know.